# SharePoint2013 - Javascript - Pagination in client side- Using listitemcollectionposition

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, client-side, paging, listitem

I am getting data from a sharepoint list based on certain filter criteria.

I am getting the records using javascript object model. This is working fine.

I am facing issue with pagination.

I have referred this article :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx

This works for "Next Page".
Doesnt work for "Previous Page" in my case, because the values are retrieved randomly. So,the IDs are not consecutive.

Does "`listItemCollectionPosition`" work only for data which is consecutive?

```
previousPagingInfo = "PagedPrev=TRUE&Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + myListItems.itemAt(0).get_item('ID');
```

This code doesnt work properly, some records are getting missed out.

Comment: The microsoft documentation on this topic is currently still non existent or useful. It's really a shame. Does Microsoft think we like to guess what to pass as pagingInfo? I sent them a feedback on the MSDN page, hope they will add additional information one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a good example here, how to page in CSOM:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92

There are some articles that gives you the following answers about paging in Sharepoint 2013.

A very important consideration to take into account:
- with JSOM or the classic webservices svc/asmx or oData, you cannot use the "$skip" particle to do paging of listitems. So it is OOTB almost impossible to do a true paging with numbers. 
For items, you have to use listItemCollectionPosition in your SOAP or using $skiptoken (oData).
The only paging possible is previous/next.

Answer (score 1):

The `listItemCollectionPosition` works for custom filtered and sorted list data.

In the link you share, there is another linked article that has an example for sorting and pagination.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92

You need to add additional values to your previousPagingInfo string to specified how you are sorting the result. In the example below I assume you are sorting your results by a list column with name "SORTCOLUMNNAME".

`previousPagingInfo = "PagedPrev=TRUE&Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + myListItems.itemAt(0).get_item('ID') + "&p_SORTCOLUMNNAME=" + myListItems.itemAt(0).getitem("SORTCOLUMNNAME");`